# Mod_wsgi Cannot Load my Python Server module on Amazon Ec2

Tags: python, apache, flask, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

Good day everyone, I am trying to deploy a test Flask project onto an Httpd (Apache) server running an Amazon Linux 2(centos rhel fedora) on Amazon Ec2. From My Apache Log I keep getting"

> Target WSGI script '/home/ssm-user/Test_Wan/FlaskApp/lado.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module." and ImportError: No module named server

**This is the error message I get on my Httpd server homepage**

[image]

**Here is the tree of my FlaskApp Directory**

[image: Flask Appp Tree View]

**This is the files in my flask app and the permisions of file and folders in it**

[image: Flask App file permissions]

**This is my lado.wsgi script**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ssm- 
user/Test_Wan/FlaskApp/server.py')

from server import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

**This is my server.py file**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template(f"index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**This is the files in my templates folder located in my FlaskAPP directory and there permissions**

[image: Permssions of files in tree directory]

**This is my HTML file Located in my templates Folder inside my FlaskApp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="title"><h1>My Blog</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="card">
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p class="text">Test Subtitle</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
    <p>Made with ♥️ in Lagos.</p>
</footer>
</html>
```

**This is the .htaccess file in my templates folder located in my FlaskApp directory**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ /home/ssm-user/Test_Wan/FlaskApp/lado.wsgi/$1
```

**This is my lado.conf file located in my /etc/http/conf.d folder**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 3.81.5x.xxx #(public IP of my EC2 instance)
        DocumentRoot /home/ssm-user/Test_Wan/FlaskApp

        WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ssm-user/Test_Wan/FlaskApp/lado.wsgi

        <Directory /home/ssm-user/Test_Wan/FlaskApp>
                WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.html

                # Additional settings for static files
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted

        </Directory>

        Alias /templates /home/ssm-user/Test_Wan/FlaskApp/templates
        <Directory /home/ssm-user/Test_Wan/FlaskApp/templates>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `server.py` from `sys.path` and retry. `sys.path` should be a directory.

Comment: Thanks, I also had to change the fstring in my server.py because python2  does not support f string.